# How to set up NFS server on Ubuntu 20.04.2?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

On [master]: NFS server Install

```
> sudo apt-get install nfs-server
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo mkdir /mirror
> sudo gedit /etc/exports
> /mirror *(rw,sync)   // write this line inside the exports file.
> sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to restart NFS Server. Unit NFS Server. Service not found.
```

I have tried many help documentations and tried different commands. This is for a piece of homework

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need internet connection on the VM to execute the installl commands which were giving me error.

1-On vm ubuntu settings click automatic dhcp

2-Close VM,Click right to settings -> network -> select simple NAT.
Done